# How to deploy an Event Receiver (C# Visual Studio Code) which writes to SQL Server Database table

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, ssom

I have created an empty SharePoint project
Added the Event Receiver - Item Added

It should do the following operations.

1. Connect to sql database.
2. Add the data to the database table.
3. Close the connection.

Nothing is working here from the event receiver.

However, the same code is working fine when I execute it in the console application.

Any suggestions/advice are greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Regards,
Natasha Gondi

Comment: can you please tell how you tried to deploy the event recevier?

Comment: Please share the code block which you have written